# What happens if RAID 1 disks get desynchronized due to a power loss?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid

What happens if during a write to a RAID 1 array I lose power, and both disks end up in different states? Will the operating system detect the array is out of sync and rebuid? Or I will think everything is OK until the filesystem crash spectacularly because both disks are in different states? Will I lose all my data?

I am interest in how Linux software RAID, in particular, handles this issue.

Answer (score 0):

mdadm will detect errors which happen when a read or write operation is performed.

Depending on the distro, there's usually a cron job that will sync the whole array (at /etc/cron.d/mdadm), which should catch any power loss, etc caused errors.

Answer (score 0):

Using command "`cat /proc/mdstat`" you can see if a disk is not working or failed

if you see something like this:

```
md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] 
      1951732 blocks super 1.2 [1/2] [U_]
```

One this is failed, (in this example sdb1)

You can search error with command "`dmesg`", if nothing special there, you can try to reattach failed this to the array with this command:

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1
```

If this work correctly, command "`cat /proc/mdstat`" to check raid reconstruction state:

```
md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      1951732 blocks [2/1] [U_]
      [=>...................]  recovery =  9.9% (1951732/1951732) finish=2.8min speed=127535K/sec
```